# Using numpy.take on multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to use take over multiple axes the same way fancy indexing works?

The multidimensional arrays are fairly large, so I was hoping to potentially get a speedup.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(20,20,20,20)
m = np.where(x>0.5)
m = (m[0],m[1],m[2])
print x[m].shape
```

Comment: Can you expand on that? Are you hoping to get the same results from your code example, but faster using `numpy.take`? Does `x[x > 0.5]` not give you the result you want?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to get better performance with take.  x[x > 0.5] is not the same as I'm only taking the first three axes of m.

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
m = np.where(x>0.5)
m = (m[0],m[1],m[2])
result = x[m]
```

Can be written to avoid the np.where by using repeat:

```
m = np.sum(x>0.5,-1)
result = x.reshape(-1,x.shape[-1]).repeat(w.ravel(), 0)
```

Which seems about 4 times faster. However I wonder if you did not mean to ask for

```
m = np.any(x>0.5,-1)
result = x[m,:]
```

which will not create duplicates (though reshaping is still required here)?